# Default numeric value from JSON property with empty string

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm trying to deserialize a JSON string, which contains an empty string value for one property... that property should be parsed into a `decimal` property of the class...

```
public class myClass {
  public decimal my_value { get; set; } = 0;
}
var json = "{ \"my_value\": \"\" }";
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<myClass>(json);
```

The issue is that data is coming back as a `null` object.

I've tried setting the property to be `decimal?`, and that does return an object, but `my_value` is `null` when I need it to default to `0`.

I've also tried the following, but it returns a `null` object (using either `decimal` or `decimal?`)...

```
  [System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue(0)]
  [JsonProperty(DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Populate)]
  public decimal my_value { get; set; } = 0;
```

How can I set this up to default to a value of `0` if the JSON contains an empty string for the property?

**Before anybody states it**... yes, the easy answer is to not have an empty string property in the JSON, but there is nothing I can do about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set up your serialization settings to ignore null values.

the settings would look like this if you are using Newtonsoft. You can learn more [here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/NullValueHandlingIgnore.htm)

```
var = jsonSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
}
```

Comment: I've deleted the previous comment because it turns out I'm an idiot... my example I'm using `0` for simplicity... but then I notice the actual code is using `decimal.MinValue` as the default value (which is, guess what, `-79228162514264337593543950335`).  So thank you, this is great